# Jquery data attribute of select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the data Attribute of a select Option but it does not work

html

```
   <select class="form-control" id="device-selection" style="width:300px;">
        <option selected="selected">Choose!</option>
        <option data-width="1080" data-height="1920">Huewai p9</option>
   </select>
```

JS:

```
    $('#device-selection').onchange = function() {
        console.log($('#device-selection').data('width'));
        console.log($('#device-selection').data('height'));
    }
```

I Keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

My Jquery Version is 3.1.1

Comment: the `data attr` is in option selector should be `$('#device-selection option:selected')`

Comment: @Olipol For some reason `$()` is returning `null`. You need to make sure your own code runs *after* jQuery has been loaded. How and where are you including jQuery? You need to post your entire code.

Comment: you are trying to get the data width and height from the `select`, but the data width and height is attr of the selected option

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#device-selection').on("change", function() {

  console.log($('option:selected',this).data('width'));
  console.log($('option:selected',this).data('height'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="device-selection" style="width:300px;">
        <option selected="selected">Choose!</option>
        <option data-width="1080" data-height="1920">Huewai p9</option>
   </select>
```

1. `Data attr` is in option selector should be `$('#device-selection option:selected')`

Comment: I get this warning `jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'on' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null` and this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null`

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery there is not method `onchange`.. Instead you can use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers to an element and pass `change` as the event parameter.

Than, in order to access the `data` attributes you can use the selected option with: `$(this).find('option:selected')` in the event handler method;

```js
$('#device-selection').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  console.log($selected.data('width'));
  console.log($selected.data('height'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="device-selection" style="width:300px;">
  <option selected="selected">Choose!</option>
  <option data-width="1080" data-height="1920">Huewai p9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write like this:

```
$( "#device-selection" ).change(function() {
    console.log($('#device-selection').data('width'));
    console.log($('#device-selection').data('height'));
});
```

Jquery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Check W3shool example :https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref

Comment: I get this warning `jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'change' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null` and this `error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of null`